# How to load a page inside a component in NextJs using JSX?

Tags: reactjs, next.js, navigation, nextjs-dynamic-routing

I'm trying to load a page inside a component

[image]

[image: looks like the component its taking the whole space]

but it's shows below the component, I have the option to add the pages inside of it but I don't know how, do you have any idea guys?

```
'use client';

import { Button, Layout, Menu } from 'antd';
import {
  HomeOutLined,
  AppstoreAddOutlined,
  AreaChartOutlined,
  UserOutlined,
  SettingOutlined,
  BarsOutlined,
  MenuUnfoldOutlined,
  MenuFoldOutlined,
} from '@ant-design/icons';

import { useSession, signOut } from 'next-auth/react';
import { useState } from 'react';

import Image from 'next/image';
import Link from 'next/link';
import { usePathname, useRouter } from 'next/navigation';

import ToggleThemeButton from './ToggleThemeButton';
import SignInPage from '@/app/login/signInPage';
import './container.css';

export default function Container() {
  const { data: session, status } = useSession();
  const { Header, Sider } = Layout;
  const [darkTheme, setDarkTheme] = useState(false);
  const [collapsed, setCollapsed] = useState(false);

  const router = useRouter();
  const pathname = usePathname();

  console.log('Pathname', pathname);

  const toggleTheme = () => {
    setDarkTheme(!darkTheme);
  };

  function getItem(label, key, href, icon, children, type) {
    return {
      key,
      href,
      icon,
      children,
      label,
      type,
    };
  }

  const items = [
    getItem('Option 1', '1', '/', <HomeOutLined />),
    getItem('Option 2', '2', '/users', <AppstoreAddOutlined />),
    getItem('Option 3', '3', '/', <AreaChartOutlined />),
    getItem('Navigation One', 'sub1', '/', <UserOutlined />, [
      getItem('Option 5', '5', '/'),
      getItem('Option 6', '6', '/'),
      getItem('Option 7', '7', '/'),
      getItem('Option 8', '8', '/'),
    ]),
    getItem('Navigation Two', 'sub2', '/', <SettingOutlined />, [
      getItem('Option 9', '9', '/'),
      getItem('Option 10', '10', '/'),
      getItem('Submenu', 'sub3', '/', null, [
        getItem('Option 11', '11', '/'),
        getItem('Option 12', '12', '/'),
      ]),
    ]),
  ];

  if (status === 'authenticated') {
    return (
      <div>
        <Layout
          className={`${darkTheme === false ? ' bg-white' : ' bg-slate-800'}`}
        >
          <Sider
            collapsed={collapsed}
            collapsible
            trigger={null}
            theme={darkTheme ? 'dark' : 'light'}
            className="sidebar"
          >
            <div className="logo">
              <div
                className={
                  darkTheme ? 'logo-dark' : 'logo-light text-yellow-600'
                }
              >
                <Link href={'/'}>HEY</Link>
              </div>
            </div>
            <Menu
              theme={darkTheme ? ' dark' : 'light'}
              className={` ${
                darkTheme === false ? 'text-red-700 bg' : 'text-slate-300'
              }`}
              defaultSelectedKeys={['1']}
              defaultOpenKeys={['sub1']}
              mode="inline"
              items={items}
            />
            <ToggleThemeButton
              darkTheme={darkTheme}
              toggleTheme={toggleTheme}
            />
          </Sider>
          <Layout
            className={` h-16${
              darkTheme === false ? 'text-zinc-800' : '  text-slate-200'
            }`}
          >
            <Header
              className={`${
                darkTheme === false
                  ? 'bg-white'
                  : ' bg-slate-900 text-slate-300'
              }`}
              style={{
                padding: 0,
                display: 'flex',
                flexDirection: 'row',
                justifyContent: 'space-between',
                alignItems: 'center',
              }}
            >
              <Button
                type="text"
                className={`toggle upside ${
                  darkTheme === false ? 'text-yellow-700' : 'text-slate-300'
                }`}
                onClick={() => setCollapsed(!collapsed)}
                icon={collapsed ? <MenuUnfoldOutlined /> : <MenuFoldOutlined />}
              />

              <div className="flex gap-x-2 items-center">
                <Link href={'/panel'}> Panel </Link>
                <p>
                  {session.user.name} {session.user.email}
                </p>
                <Image
                  className="rounded-full"
                  src={session?.user?.image}
                  width={60}
                  height={60}
                  alt="user-image"
                  referrerPolicy="no-referrer"
                />

                <Button
                  onClick={() =>
                    signOut({
                      callbackUrl: '/',
                    })
                  }
                  className="bg-slate-900 text-white px-6 py-2 rounded-md"
                >
                  Cerrar Sesion
                </Button>
              </div>
            </Header>
            <div>I'm trying to load the pages here</div>
          </Layout>
        </Layout>
      </div>
    );
  } else {
    return <SignInPage />;
  }
}
```

I'm trying to use map in the menu secction to go to the path, (to try if allow me to go there at least but don't) and then add the data inside the blank space section

```
<Menu
              theme={darkTheme ? ' dark' : 'light'}
              className={` ${
                darkTheme === false ? 'text-red-700 bg' : 'text-slate-300'
              }`}
              defaultSelectedKeys={['1']}
              defaultOpenKeys={['sub1']}
              mode="inline"
              items={items.map((link)=>{
                <Link href={link.href} key={link.key}></Link>
              })}
            />
```

Comment: I could find the issue, looks like there is a different syntaxis and now should have a return

`<Menu
              theme={darkTheme ? ' dark' : 'light'}
              className={` ${
                darkTheme === false ? 'text-red-700 bg' : 'text-slate-300'
              }`}
              defaultSelectedKeys={['1']}
              defaultOpenKeys={['sub1']}
              mode="inline"
              items={items.map((link)=>{
                return<Link href={link.href} key={link.key}></Link>
              })}
            />`